# Ошибка при авторизации

Tags: php

Мне при проверки логина и пароля выбивает такую ошибку:

> `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\style\checklogin.php`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это значит? Ошибка здесь :

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count > 0) {
    $userinfo             = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $_SESSION['id']       = $userinfo->id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo->username;
    $_SESSION['level']    = $userinfo->level;
    header("location:game.php?page=pokemons");
    exit;
}

else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: А откуда берется `$result`?

Comment: Полный скрипт опубликуйте.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password= md5($password)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: @Prikol! В ответах на Ваш вопрос "Регистрация пароля с md5" Вам уже давали совет, **что** надо сделать. А Вы опять не пишете исходные данные.

Comment: О-да, там ответ зашибись =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит, что ваш **mysql_query** вернул **False** из-за того, что в запросе была ошибка.
Можно так попробовать:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$tbl_name.'` WHERE `username`=\''.$username.'\' and `password`=\''. md5($password).'\'';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

UPD: Таблица для авторизации обычно имеет конкретное имя, потому видится странным использование **$tbl_name**